# ORDER BY not working in MySQL 5.1

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by, where-clause, sql-like

I have a problem with sql query in php:

```
select
    user, name, outlet, switch, port, vlan, mac, status
from access where 
    user like '%'
    and name like '%'
    and outlet like '%'
    and switch like '%'
    and port like '%'
    and vlan like '%'
    and mac like '%'
    and status like '%'
order by 'user';
```

When running query on MySQL client version: 5.1.36 query doesn't work totally (ORDER BY won't work), however when running SAME query on MySQL client version: 4.1.13, ORDER BY works!

I have checked nearly all manuals about ORDER BY, WHERE, LIKE commands, but no result. No mention about version differences, etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to remove the quotes from `user` in the `ORDER BY` clause. This is what is causing the `ORDER BY` not working as expected, because you can use any expression in the `ORDER BY` clause, and the `'user'` in quotes is being considered an expression (constant) instead of a column name.

Test case (MySQL 5.1.45):

```
CREATE TABLE tb (id int);

INSERT INTO tb VALUES (5);
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (1);
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (4);
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (2);
INSERT INTO tb VALUES (3);

SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY 'id';
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    5 |
|    1 |
|    4 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

SELECT * FROM tb ORDER BY id;
+------+
| id   |
+------+
|    1 |
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
|    5 |
+------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Fixed the problem with code (copy paste mistake).
The solution with quotes is working!
Funny that, so it seems that v. 4.1.13 works with quotes, however v 5. does not.

Comment: Yes, that's interesting. However, I suggest not using quotes around column names. You can use backticks instead: ``user``

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is:

```
SELECT `user`,`name`,`outlet`,`switch`,`port`,`vlan`,`mac`,`status` 
FROM `access`
WHERE `user` like '%' 
    AND `name` like '%'
    AND `outlet` like '%'
    AND `switch` like '%'
    AND `port` like '%'
    AND `vlan` like '%'
    AND `mac` like '%'
    AND `status` like '%' 
ORDER BY `user`;
```

Though I don't understand your `WHERE` clause. It doesn't filter on any of the fields.
EDIT; some of your column names (`user`, `name`, `port` and `status`) could be MySQL keywords. Try enclosing them in grave accents (`) (I added them to my post as well).

Comment: Or better yet renaming them. Names like that set my teeth on edge. Arrggghh.

Comment: Thanks Rfvgyhn, I've updated my post. @le dorfier; you're absolutely right.